# Mobile display depends on RewriteCond format

Tags: apache, mobile

When a visitor asks for a1.html I want to serve a1.html if they're on a desktop and m_a1.html if they're on a mobile.

I have the mod_rewrite directives below in  of my httpd.conf file:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android
    RewriteRule ^/281/a1.html /281/m_a1.html
```

If I request the file on my S7 this works fine.  I get the m_a1.html file and it looks fine on the S7.

Now if I change the RewriteCond line to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Android|iPhone     [NC]
```

to allow iPhone accesses and try it again on the S7, I still get the right file (m_a1.html) but it's not centered anymore on the S7 screen.  It's offset to the left. Does anyone understand how this could affect the placement of the page on the S7?  Thanks.

Comment: That's impossible. The layout can't be affected by this change, unless you don't get redirected to `m_a1.html` and actually view the original desktop version.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I thought.  There must be something else going on. In general, what could cause a page to not be centered on a mobile?

Comment: There's a gazillion of possible causes, but I can ask my crystal ball :-)